# json_encode() converts large number to scientific notation

Tags: php, json, scientific-notation

I am receiving an array of json objects (example below). I need to loop through them and output the json objects individually. One of the values "MessageID" is a large number and when I run json_encode(), its getting encoded with scientific notation. That won't work for me because the number is a database key.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$events = json_decode($json);

foreach($events as $event){
  $debug = var_export($event, true); //still see the whole number here!
  $event_json = json_encode($event); //number is converted to scientific notation
  //code to create records in database
}
?>
```

Example input json:

```
[{
   "event": "open",
   "time": 1433103519,
   "MessageID": 19421777396190490,
   "email": "api@mailjet.com",
   "mj_campaign_id": 7173,
   "mj_contact_id": 320,
   "customcampaign": "",
   "CustomID": "helloworld",
   "Payload": "",
   "ip": "127.0.0.1",
   "geo": "US",
   "agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0"
}]
```

I tried inserting the following to change the number to a string but it had no effect.

```
$event["MessageID"]=(string)$event["MessageID"]
```

How would I convert the MessageID property to a string or is there another way to get this to output the same way it came in?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to encode each object again ? Can't you use it directly without decode it first...?

Comment: @Elementary because I am saving the object to a database record (in FileMaker) where I want to work with it as JSON.